# The group of fixed points of an involution of a Weyl group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, coxeter-groups, root-systems

Let $R$ be a reduced root system in a vector space  $V$ over $\mathbb Q$.
Let $W=W(R)$ denote its Weyl group.
Let $S\subset R$ be a basis of $R$ (a system of simple roots).
Let $D=D(R,S)$ denote the corresponding Dynkin diagram with the set of vertices $S$.

Let $\tau$ be an involution (an automorphism of order dividing 2) of the pair $(V,R)$.
Then $\tau$ acts on the Weyl group $W=W(R)=W(D)$.
I would like to compute the group of fixed points $W^\tau$ of $\tau$ in $W$.

The automorphism $\tau$ acts on the basis $S$ and on the Dynkin diagram $D$ via the *$*$-action*.
Namely, consider the basis $\tau(S)$ of $R$.
There exists a unique element $w=w_{\tau,S}\in W$ such that $w(\tau(S))=S$.
We set $\tau_*=w\circ\tau\in{\rm Aut}(V,R)$.
Then $\tau_*(S)=S$ and $\tau_*^2={\rm id}_S$. Moreover, $\tau_*$ is an involution of $D=D(R,S)$.
Using the involution $\tau_*$ of $D$, one can construct the *twisted Dynkin diagram* $_{\tau_*} D$,
whose vertices are the orbits of $\tau_*$ in $S$.

> **Question.** Is it true that $W^\tau\simeq W(\,_{\tau_*} D)$ ?

If yes, I would be grateful for a proof or reference.

> **Remark.** Since the root system $(V,R)$ canonically decomposes into a direct sum of irreducible root systems, the question reduces to the case when our root system $(V,R)$ is irreducible.

Comment: I think Corollary 13.1.4 in "Simple groups of Lie type" by R. Carter is very close to what you are looking for in case $\tau_*$ is non-trivial.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky: Yes, it is close, but not exactly what I am looking for. Carter starts from an automorphism of a *basis*  (say...) of a root system, whereas I start from an arbitrary automorphism of order 2 of the  root system.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi what about the following example? let $R=A_n$ and $\tau(v)=-v$. Then $w$ is the longest element in the weyl group which is the transposition $(1,n)(2,n-1)...$ and our automorphism of the simple roots takes $e_j-e_i$ to $e_(n-i) - e_(n-j)$ so it folds the diagram to a $B_k$ for $k$ roughly $n/2$, which have smaller Weyl group isn't it?

Comment: @S.carmeli: You are right! My conjecture was wrong. Thank you, Shachar!